# ajax responseText displayed as text, not html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following problem.

My Table contains rows which show simple information about an article. If you click on a label, a new `<tr>` gets inserted.

In that `<tr>` information is displayed. But the problem is, it gets displayed like you view a html document in an Editor.

Like this:
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-32" /> <title>Untitled Document</title> <link href="css/test2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"> .......`

Not as "translated" html, like it usually does.

The Code i use:

```
function doDetail(articlenr)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiceXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var partr = document.getElementById("tr"+articlenr);
            var newtr = document.createElement("TR");
            var newtd = document.createElement("TD");
            var content = document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText);
            newtr.setAttribute('id', "det"+articlenr);
            newtd.colSpan = 8;

            newtd.appendChild(content);
            newtr.appendChild(newtd);
            partr.parentNode.insertBefore(newtr,partr.nextSibling);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","showdetail.php?nr="+articlenr,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: FYI, you have a typo: `ActiceXObject` should be `ActiveXObject`.

Comment: Oh... thank you.. good to know..Firebug dont saw this Typo :D

Comment: It will only cause an error if that line is executed, which will only happen on old IE versions.

Comment: okay. I will force everyone in my company to use Firefox when my site is completed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ajax responseText displayed as text, not html

Yes, you're *explicitly* doing that with this line:

```
var content = document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

...and then appending that line to `newtd`.

If you want the text parsed as HTML, you can assign it to the `innerHTML` property of an element. E.g.:

```
newtd.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Thank you. But what i have to do with the "newtd.appendChild(Content) ? ... just delete ?

Comment: @user3108507: Yes, you don't need that `content` thing at all.

Comment: Note that the `<head>` section and `<script>` tags will be ignored.

Comment: Uhm..i think those are not needed anyway...These get created automatically by Dreamweaver... but if the get ignored...why does the Stylesheet link work?

Answer (score 0):

`Replace newtd.appendChild(content);` width `newtd.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`